# Classic editor showing in Gutenberg when creating a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor

I'm building a theme using Gutenberg for the first time. In the past, I've built custom post types like this:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Post Types', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Post Type', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => false,
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

When this is added to functions.php, the classic editor appears when creating a post.

I assume I need to enable the post type in REST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you just need to add `'show_in_rest' => true`

Here's the full snippet:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Post Types', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Post Type', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => false,
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of WordPress ( 5.1 RC), Gutenberg is only visible for the default pages and post types. Since WordPress custom post types are almost everywhere, the unavailability of Gutenberg editor is something that the community has been talking about since the release of WordPress 5.0.
First you have to Register Gutenberg WordPress Custom Post Type

```
/*Register WordPress  Gutenberg CPT */
function cw_post_type() {

    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
        // WordPress CPT Options Start
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio' )
            ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),

        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cw_post_type' );
```

Now Add Gutenberg Support to WordPress Custom Post Types

```
'show_in_rest' => true,
   'supports' => array('editor')
```

Here is the complete details about [Use Gutenberg with WordPress Custom Post Types](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/gutenberg-wordpress-custom-post-type/)